# Execution failed for task ':android_intent:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':android_intent:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

\> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org BUILD FAILED in 7s

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I tried updating the android intent and run flutter clean but its not working

The build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.5.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```